# Selecting in SQL the most recent record with dates which do not match

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a large number of records (tens of thousands) contained in one table called Former_Customer_ID_List (unique ID numbers of clients who are former as of now), which I need to join with a second table called Records_List which contains millions of rows of data seperately on these customers with a daily snapshot taken and logged in called "Recorded as of" . Given that these are former customers all dates of the snapshots can be different given each customer could have left at a different timeframe. I would like to extract the most recent "Recorded as of" date for each of the former customers from Former_Customer_ID_List and not retunr the older snapshots in Records_List . I found a way to filter this via powerquery but it seems to be less than an optimal solution.

Here's an example of the table called Records_List

| Customer_ID | Customer Name | Recorded as of |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Fun Company LLC | 28/12/2022 |
| 123 | Fun Company LLC | 29/12/2022 |
| 123 | Fun Company Inc | 01/01/2023 |
| 458 | Hello Inc | 12/01/2022 |
| 458 | Hello Inc | 14/01/2022 |
| 458 | Hello Inc | 16/01/2022 |
| 999 | XYZ Company Inc | 03/08/2020 |
| 999 | XYZ Company Inc | 06/08/2020 |
| 999 | XYZ Company Inc | 07/08/2020 |
| 999 | XYZ Company Inc | 08/08/2020 |

Here's an example simple join query which would return all matches but does not filter the most recent records. Hence the query instead of return 20K records returns 19 million records

```
SELECT *
FROM Former_Customer_ID_List
INNER JOIN Records_List ON Records_List.Customer_ID = Former_Customer_ID_List.Customer_ID;
```

Ideally I was interested in trying to get the following result

Final part

| Customer_ID | Customer Name | Recorded as of |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Fun Company Inc | 01/01/2023 |
| 458 | Hello Inc | 16/01/2022 |
| 999 | XYZ Company Inc | 08/08/2020 |

Thank you for any suggestions/advice.

Comment: could you also provide example input format for Former_Customer_ID_List in the post? in the current descritpion, it doen't seems you need to use Former_Customer_ID_List  at all to get the output you want.

Comment: @nbk Thank you for sharing. This is really useful. I was able to apply this,  and get a number of rows for the dataset which then can be filtered via WHERE. The issue I encountered is that the table "Records_List " I am selecting from is not ordered by "Recorded as of" and  "CustomerID". So I end up getting the oldest or random records it seems.

Comment: @jonathan200 , the Former_Customer_ID_List is extracted/created as a volatile table from another different major table which contains Customer IDs of various business departments, the ones I need relate only to my department rather than the whole firm.

Comment: i don't understand oldest means that  "Recorded as of" has the order if there are multiple equal dates you need a second order column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use SQL [window function](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-window-functions/) to get the most recent record of each customer and join with Former_Customer_ID_List to get the final result you want.

For the 1st part ( get the most recent record of each customer), here is the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9d310e/4):

```
with Records_List_with_rank AS (
select
    Customer_ID,
    "Customer Name",
    "Recorded as of",
     row_number() over(partition by Customer_ID order by "Recorded as of" desc) as row_num
from
    Records_List
)
select
     Customer_ID,
    "Customer Name",
    "Recorded as of"
from
    Records_List_with_rank
where
    row_num = 1
```

| Customer_ID | Customer Name | Recorded as of |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Fun Company Inc | 2023-01-01 |
| 458 | Hello Inc | 2022-01-14 |
| 999 | XYZ Company Inc | 2020-08-08 |

For the 2nd part to join with Former_Customer_ID_List, here is the query:

```
with Records_List_with_rank AS (
select
    Customer_ID,
    "Customer Name",
    "Recorded as of",
     row_number() over(partition by Customer_ID order by "Recorded as of" desc) as row_num
from
    Records_List
)
select
    *
FROM
Former_Customer_ID_List
INNER JOIN
    Records_List_with_rank 
ON Records_List_with_rank.Customer_ID = Former_Customer_ID_List.Customer_ID
AND Records_List_with_rank.row_num = 1
```